# Eslint not ignoring node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, eslint, babel-eslint

Somehow after updating `Babel` from `6` to `7` my `eslint` started giving such a warning in `node_modules`:

[image]

So, from my understanding `node_modules` folder is not ignored and that is why the issue popped up. So, reading through `eslint` docs:

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

I tried adding `"ignorePatterns": ["node_modules/"],` to the `.eslintrc` file but got an error:

> Module build failed: Error: ESLint configuration in /Users/vlasenkona/Desktop/gris-seqr2/ui/.eslintrc is invalid:
>       - Unexpected top-level property "ignorePatterns".

So, I tried creating `.eslintignore` file and added there just `node_modules/` but the warning stayed the same. How could I ignore the `node_modules` folder? The versions of the packages I am using:

```
"eslint": "^5.16.0",
"babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
"eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-perf": "^2.0.8",
```

The `.eslintrc` looks like that:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:react-perf/recommended"
  ],  
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }   
  },  
  "env": {
    "mocha": true,
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },  
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }   
  },  
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-shadow": ["error", { "allow": ["error"] }], 
    "arrow-body-style": 0,
    "func-names": 0,
    "function-paren-newline": 0,
    "max-len": 0, //["warn", 80, 2], 
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-multi-str": 0,
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "no-plusplus": 0,
    "brace-style": 0,
    "object-curly-newline": 0,
    "padded-blocks": 0,
    "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
    "react/sort-comp": 0,  // more freedom in arranging class functions
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "no-class-assign": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [ 1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]} ],
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "react/require-optimization": 2,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-target-blank": 0,
    "spaced-comment": 0,

    "jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/tabindex-no-positive": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0
  }
}
```

> Update

I tried adding the following to newly created `.eslintignore`:

```
node_modules/*
./node_modules/**
**/node_modules/**
```

But neither works. Interestingly enough, if I open `./node_modules/draftjs-md-converter/dist/index.js` and put at the very beginning and end of the file `/*eslint-disable */` the warning still remains, so maybe it is not an `eslint` problem: just totally misleading warning?..

Comment: Ignore all node_modules folder with `node_modules/*` in `.eslintignore`

Comment: I tried this too and the error stays the same

Comment: Tried also downgrading `eslint` to version `4.19.1` but no luck

Comment: I'm having a similar issue... @NikitaVlasenko did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope, I was not. I am really stuck with that, so if you manage to solve it, please, let me know.

Comment: My problem was that another folder isn't supposed to be run with eslint, this folder is a build file, and somehow in the .eslintignore, it's named wrong. By running the eslint command with ` > log.txt`, then check the log file, i knew about the folder. After I removed it/ fixed .eslintignore, it's fixed!

Comment: Try updating your `eslint` and related packages to latest version. Might help.

Comment: According to docs "ESLint always ignores files in `/node_modules/**` and `/bower_components/**`", so ignoring it explicitly should not be required. It can be some dependency has the config where `node_modules` is added to the list. Try running `eslint -v`, it will tell you which configs are in use, then investigate where path is added.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko any workaround for this in 2021?

Comment: Since I could not solve it with any answers posted, ultimately I abandoned updates at all, and just working with outdated babel. Unfortunately thats what it is.

Comment: Is there a github issue open for this? Maybe they're not aware of it?

Comment: For me it was resolved using a higher node.js version, the server was using 12.x.x but 16.x.x works fine.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, ESLint (v7.8.1) was ignoring `node_modules` directories properly, but not my `dist` directory. I added this to `.eslintignore`:

```
client/dist/
```

and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I shouldn't have had a second node_modules folder in the first place, it works with using only the main folder now

---

Ignoring `node_modules/` in the .eslintignore file in the root folder worked for me.

`node_modules/*` did not, it caused "An unhandled exception occurred: Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from." or similar errors when linting the sub-project.

Our project structure looks like this:

##### root-project

- *node_modules*
- projects

  - sub-project

    - *node_modules*
    - package.json
    - .eslintrc.json
    - ...
- src
- .eslintignore
- .eslintrc.json
- ...

Answer (score 3):

For me, **it was my node version**. I was running 14 and `eslint` server was running on 16. This caused `eslint` to lint all of my node modules.

If you're using `nvm`, switch to a newer node:

```bash
nvm use 18
```

You can see the ESLint node server version in your IDE using the `ESLint: Show Output Channel` command.

---

- `nvm`: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 2):

I had the following script in my `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint **/*.ts",
  }
```

It turns out that my shell was expanding the glob, so it passed all `.ts` files as arguments to `eslint` (including the ones in `node_modules`), causing the ignore rules of `eslint` to not be applied.

I fixed it by changing the script to pass the glob to eslint rather than expanding it:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.ts'",
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem.
Solution:
  Make sure your file ".eslintrc" is in the root directory of your project. Where is package.json, node_modules and other things. Good luck.

Comment: For me, `.eslintrc` is already in the folder where these other files are located. Moving it to the root of the large project that I have would be wrong logically.