# ng lint node:internal/process/promises:246

Tags: angular-cli, eslint

My node version is `16.13.0` and I'm using angular 14
The following is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "01.06.05",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node ./replace.build.js && ng serve --open",
    "build": "ng lint && node ./replace.build.js && ng build --configuration=production --build-optimizer --optimization --extract-licenses=false",
    "publish": "npm run build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "highcharts": "^10.2.1",
    "hover.css": "^2.3.2",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mds.persian.datetime": "^1.5.0",
    "mermaid": "^9.1.6",
    "ngx-markdown": "^14.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "three": "^0.144.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/mermaid": "^8.2.9",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.14",
    "@types/recordrtc": "^5.6.8",
    "@types/three": "^0.144.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.36.1",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.4.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash-extend": "^1.0.13",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

I have the following eslint config:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts",
        "*.js",
        "*.tsx"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "indent": [
          "error",
          2,
          {
            "SwitchCase": 1
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "error",
        "quotes": "error",
        "semi": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "error",
        "comma-dangle": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html",
        "*.css"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-elements-content": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the following is `angular.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "./src/index.html",
            "main": "./src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "./src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.json",
            "assets": [
              "./src/assets",
              "./src/favicon.ico",
              "./src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./src/bootstrap-custom.css",
              "./node_modules/hover.css/css/hover-min.css",
              "./src/materials-custom.css",
              "./src/styles.css",
              "./src/rtl.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "./src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "./src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-project:build",
            "proxyConfig": "./proxy.config.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-project:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-project:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "./src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "./src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./src/bootstrap-custom.css",
              "./node_modules/hover.css/css/hover-min.css",
              "./src/materials-custom.css",
              "./src/styles.css",
              "./src/rtl.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "./src/assets",
              "./src/favicon.ico",
              "./src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I use `ng lint` command the following error raised:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Object>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

I test uninstalling some packages, no changes!
How can I detect the problem?
How can I detect the problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eslint not ignoring node\_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192096/eslint-not-ignoring-node-modules-folder)

Comment: No, I added `lint` block to `angular.json` to process `"src/**/*.ts"` files, I'll add angular.json to question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had same issue. In my case there was trailing comma in tsconfig.json.
How to get error stacktrace:

1. Use node v16.15+
2. Run `ng lint` again to see full stack trace, to see error

In my case it was property missing error, because of unnecessary comma after last option in `compilerOptions` and config reader thought that after comma should be another property with value.

Comment: the error was result of `ng lint` with node 6.13, I update my node to 16.17, unbelievably `ng lint` report the problem with new node, I removed the problem and now everything is OK, after 1 week  :))